# prevent email change in azure b2c custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

is there a way to prevent email change during password reset?

there is standard policy for password restoring but I do not like changing email there. This email is used as id for integration with other applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change email during password reset is not changing the users actual email. It’s there in case the user verifies an email but then realised that’s not the email for which they wanted to reset the password for. This control cannot be disabled, but the change email button could be hidden with CSS.

Comment: Clicking on the "change email" button returns to the screen to input an email to send a verification code. I see the reasoning here but it isn't clear. Should probably say "Use different email"

Answer (score 0):

I refer here only to password reset custom policy. The change email button can be done with JavaScript, altering CSS but it is very cumbersome (as the CSS and JavaScript injected by MS changes the inline style of elements) and don't know if it will run by next MS changes?!
Did something like this:

```
var mail_ver_but_edit = $('#email_ver_but_edit');
if (mail_ver_but_edit) {
   mail_ver_but_edit.attr ('style', 'display: none;');
   mail_ver_but_edit.removeAttr('id');
   mail_ver_but_edit.removeClass('editButton');
}
```