# Forgot Password in Azure AD B2C

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I was using Azure `AD B2C` MSAL integration in android. I have created the `UserFlow` for `ForgotPassword` which is working as expected. When I tried to change the Password, they will ask for the registered `emailAddress` where they will send the verification code to change the Password. But when I tried to give any `emailAddress` during forgot password it will be sending the `verification code` to any email which I provided . How can I handle sending verification code to any `emailAddress` unless that `emailAddress` is `signedup` in azure

Comment: I think that's a usual work flow, if you wanna change password and you need to get verification code first, you need to provide an email address which you could used to receive the code, it shouldn't be restricted to some specific accounts, because nobody could make sure that they can access those accounts at that time. By the way, if you enter a wrong email address, you can't get code to pass the validation, and those who received the code also have no place to use the code.

Comment: @Tiny-wa - yeah ,I got your point. But what if we send the verification code to some random mail which is in the name of some famous person and they will get the verification code even though they are not registered with the azure ad b2c. so do we need to restrict that?

Comment: I think it's all up to you. You could validate the mail account if it's illegal, for example xx@1.com, it seems a wrong address right? By the way, for myself, the validation mail contains code I've received usually in a format like '[company A], the code is 123456, please never share it to others, pls contact 123456 when you have questions'. If I haven't done those operations, I would feel being disturbed at most.

Comment: I think what you should do is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) which is used to validate address.

Comment: @Tiny-wa - Actually I think, you haven't got my point. I will explain in Detail. Suppose I have my Android App registered With `Azure AD B2C` with an email `abc@gmail.com`. When I tried to change the Password using `forgot password`.It asks for the email to send the verification code. But when I tried using an email ' cde@gmail.com` to change the password of `abc@gmail.com`. Still verification is received on  ' cde@gmail.com` even though  `cde@gmail.com` is not registered with my App using `AD B2C`. so i have to prevent sending  verification code to email address which is still not registered

Comment: Yes, thanks. So, regardless of the feature you wanted could be achieved, from my point of view, the reset password flow should like this: 'is xx@xx.com still in use? we'll send code to it', and provide a choice to change the mail address to avoid the situation that user can't use the email that used to register in your app to receive validation code. And along with your idea, I haven't found a solution to achieve the feature to restrict entering the mail address that used to register the app.

Comment: I watched this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and I found a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703642/prevent-email-change-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in this sample

Demonstrate how to use a displayControl to send One-Time-Passcodes to users only if the email is registered against a user in the directory.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists