# How to stop Azure AD B2C signin flow to allow users to change email

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented Azure AD B2C sign-in flow in my application and enabled self-service password change for it. Everything works fine except that in forget password process if after a user verify the email address they have the option to change their email too; and because our authorization is based on email it can cause lots of suffering.

How can I remove the change email button and process from the forget password process.

Comment: There is no "setting.show" for this button so JavaScript?

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703642/prevent-email-change-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JasSuri-MSFT,

Change email during password reset is not changing the user's actual email. It’s there in case the user verifies an email but then realized that’s not the email for which they wanted to reset the password for. This control cannot be disabled, but the change email button could be hidden with CSS.

Comment: The button should really be named **"Recover password for another account"** instead of **"Change E-Mail"**. The users are super confused and I thought its finally possible to let the local users change their emails by themselves if they want to switch to another.